# Convert string [object Object ] to objects?

Tags: javascript

I get objects converted to string in this format: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Howe can i convert it to normal objects?

Comment: A little unclear - while Quentin is right, if you perhaps change your method of converting to string, you could preserve the object information in JSON. And use that to recreate your objects. Perhaps if you just expand on your question you will get better help.

Comment: Can you explain more on what you were doing when you got a series of [object Object]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

The information in each object was lost when they were converted to strings.

It isn't a reversible transformation.